# MySQL - update groups of records in one hit

Tags: mysql, sql

lets's say that i have a table `users` and i want to set the `foo` field to `"bar"` for users with `id in (1,5,10)` and to `"qux"` for users with `id in (3,8,15)`, and that generally i might have more values and more groups of ids to go with each value.

Currently (in my scripting language of choice) i'm looping over the pairs of values of foo and groups of ids, like this (pseudocode)

```
for(val, ids) in my_array
  execute_sql("update users set foo = '#{val}' where id in (#{ids.join(',')})")
end
```

Is there a way i can do this in a single sql command, instead of one command per pair?

Comment: It would be nice if you could have some sort of group_id then you could do a join and get rid of the in clauses, especially if the lists of ids get big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in SQL by using the `case` statement.  The query would look like:

```
update users u
    set foo = (case when id in (1, 5, 10) then 'bar'
                    when id in (3, 8, 15) then 'qux'
                    else foo
               end)
    where id in (1, 5, 10) or id in (3,  8, 15);
```

Note:  the `else` is not strictly needed, so long as the lists in the `where` and `when` statements match.  But it is safer.

Also, the `in` lists in the `where` could be combined into one.  However, I think it is clearer because this matches the `case` statement logic.

Comment: @Strawberry, it's there to keep transaction size down.

Comment: @jarlh Well, that's fair enough, I guess.

Comment: That makes sense - the case will only be run on records which we already know match *one* of the cases then, rather than running the case on all records.  My table is large so this is an important consideration.

Comment: Do you think there is any limit on the number of cases?  Eg if i had 1000 cases, do we get to the point where a) the query just breaks because of some sort of internal limit or b) it becomes significantly slower than just running 1000 seperate `set foo = 'bar' where id in ()` queries?

Comment: @MaxWilliams You will probably get to a point where a join will prove more efficient. Suck it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` to chose update value:

```
update users
  set foo = case when id in (1,5,10) then 'bar'
                 when id in (3,8,15) then 'qux'
                 else foo end

where id in (1,5,10) or id in (3,8,15)
```

The `WHERE` clause is there to keep transaction size down, but doesn't affect the result of the `UPDATE`.